# Prolog: How to get the number of output?

Tags: prolog

I have the following facts:

```
/* facts */
parent(parent1, child1).
parent(parent2, child1).
parent(parent1, child2).
parent(parent2, child2).
parent(parent1, child3).
parent(parent2, child3).
parent(parent1, child4).
parent(parent2, child4).

/* rule */
childof(X, Y):- parent(Y ,X).
```

I am trying to make the output display the number of children of a parent. In my case, my parent1 have 4 children. But how I can make the output display the number '4'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Collect all the answers

```
?- 
bagof(X,childof(X,parent1),Xs).

Xs = [child1,child2,child3,child4].
```

2. Count them

```
?- 
bagof(X,childof(X,parent1),Xs),
length(Xs,Count).

Xs = [child1,child2,child3,child4],
Count = 4.
```

Pack the above into a procedure for later re-use:

```
numberofchild(Parent, Count) :-
   bagof(Child,childof(Child,Parent),Children),
   length(Children,Count).
```

Then:

```
?- numberofchild(parent1, Count).
Count = 4.
```

Note that the call fails if there are no children:

```
?- numberofchild(foo, Count).
false.
```

Or if the number of children stated is not correct:

```
?- numberofchild(parent1, 444).
false.
```

We can enumerate:

```
?- numberofchild(Parent,Count).
Parent = parent1,
Count = 4 ;
Parent = parent2,
Count = 4.
```

Comment: What if the question asks for the rule? As an example: numberofchild(X, Y).

Comment: @Hingusan See adendum

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [library(aggregate)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)